# Yahoo Finance API Problems

Tags: urllib2, yahoo-finance, http-error

My code was working fine a few days ago but since Friday, I have been getting the following error:

```
 File "C:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
 urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Server Error
```

All I'm doing is accessing the historical data from the API. Is anyone else having this problem? Is the problem actually on the Yahoo servers? Is there a possibility that I'm sending too many requests (asking for historical data of 100 stocks)?

Comment: Can you please share the endpoint you are querying? Some more context would be really helpful.

Comment: Why don't you add a try - except block ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also having the same issue.  I am using this query:

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22APPL%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=
```

I am using

```
>  Try
>        
>         objWebRequest = CType(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(strScrapeString),
> System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
>         objWebRequest.KeepAlive = False
>         objWebRequest.Method = "GET"
>         **objWebResponse = CType(objWebRequest.GetResponse(), System.Net.HttpWebResponse)** *(this is where it fails on debug)*
> 
> 
> ...
>             
>             objWebResponse.Close()
>          
> 
>             Return strStockPrice
> 
>         Catch ex As Exception
>             strResults = strResults + "<br/>" + "**ERROR**" + strSymbol + " Yahoo data not available.  Exception Error Message : " +
> ex.Message.ToString()
>         End Try
```

I can see that I am getting the 
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error
on some stocks, but it isn't always the same ones.  I am getting stock prices for about 40 stocks at a time.
Yahoo Finance has a limit of 2000 requests per hour for this query and if you exceed that it should error out with 403 error, so I do not think overuse is the cause of the 500 error.  I am using a Try, Catch in my code around the objWebRequest.GetResponse.